# An iterative/recursive optimization problem about minimizing the Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

Firstly, solve the initial problem:

$$
\varphi_0 = \underset{\varphi}{\arg\min}\lVert \left( \varphi ^{\top}\varphi -I \right) X \rVert _{F}^{2},
$$

s.t.

$$
\lVert \varphi_0 \rVert _2=1,
$$

where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, $\varphi_0\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ is a vector, $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ is a given matrix (dataset).

Secondly, for each $i \in \left\{ 1,2,\cdots, q  \right\} $, get the best $\varphi_i\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ by solving the following problem iteratively:

$$
\varphi_i = \underset{\varphi}{\arg\min}\lVert \left( A_i ^{\top}A_i+\varphi ^{\top}\varphi -I \right) X \rVert _{F}^{2},
$$

s.t.

$$
\lVert \varphi_i \rVert _2=1,
$$
where

$$
A_i=\left( \begin{array}{c}
 \varphi _0\\
 \cdots\\
 \varphi _{i-1}\\
\end{array} \right) _{i\times n}.
$$

The final $A_{q}$ composed of $q$ unit vectors is what I need.

Comment: If $\varphi_0$ is a scalar, then what do you mean by $\|\varphi_0\|_2$?

Comment: If $\varphi_0$ is a vector, then what is $\varphi$?

Comment: I missed that it was arg min rather than min; everything is clear

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question, now all known conditions are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This amounts to an application of the [EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation). If $X$ has singular value decomposition $X = U\Sigma V^T$ and $U$ has columns $u_1,\dots,u_n$, then we will find that
$$
A_q = \pmatrix{u_1^T\\ \vdots \\ u_q^T}.
$$

Comment: So nice. Does an upper row in $A_q$ correspond to a larger singular value? Are there any other properties of $A_q$?

Comment: Yes, the corresponding singular values are $\sigma_1 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_q$