# Find $\mathbf{A}$ minimizing $\lVert \mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{AX}-\mathbf{X} \rVert _{F}^{2}$ with a given $\mathbf{X}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, optimization, convex-optimization

**$1.$ Problem:**

There are three subproblems:

$(1.1)$ Given a data matrix $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times D}$, find a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N} (M\ll N)$ satisfying:

$$
\mathbf{A}=\underset{\mathbf{A}}{\arg\min}\lVert\mathbf{A}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{X}\rVert_F^2.
$$

$(1.2)$ Given a data matrix $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times D}$, find a bipolar matrix $\mathbf{B}\in \mathbb{Z}^{M\times N} (M\ll N)$ and a scaling factor $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying:

$$
\mathbf{C}=\underset{\mathbf{C}}{\arg\min}\lVert\mathbf{C}^\top\mathbf{C}\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{X}\rVert_F^2,~~~~\text{s.t.}~\mathbf{C}=\alpha\mathbf{B},
$$

$~~~~~~$where each element of $\mathbf{B}$ can only be choosed from $\{-1,+1\}$.

$(1.3)$ Based on $(1.2)$, could you please get an optimal binary matrix $\mathbf{C}$ (*i.e.*, each element of $\mathbf{B}$ can only be choosed from $\{0,1\}$)?

---

**$2.$ Background:**

(Compressed Sensing)

$(2.1)$ I project an $N$-dimensional dataset (with $D$ data points) into an $M$-dimensional space by $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{AX}$ and then reconstruct it by $\mathbf{\hat{X}}=\mathbf{A^\top Y}=\mathbf{A^\top AX}$. I want to get an optimal $\mathbf{A}$ such that the $\ell_2$-error between $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{X}}$ is minimized.

$(2.2)$ For higher compression efficiency and lower memory complexity of $\mathbf{A}$, I want to get a bipolar $\mathbf{C}$ that may works well or close to floating-point $\mathbf{A}$.

---

**$3.$ My Efforts:**

$(3.1)$ I think I can solve subproblem $(1.1)$ by singular value decomposition (SVD) of $\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{U\Sigma V^\top}$ with singular values $\sigma_i=\mathbf{\Sigma}_{i,i}$ satisfying $\sigma_1\ge \sigma_2\ge\cdots\ge \sigma_N$. The optimal $\mathbf{A}$ should be formed by the first $M$ rows of $\mathbf{U}^\top$ [[Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905972/an-iterative-recursive-optimization-problem-about-minimizing-the-frobenius-norm)].

$(3.2)$ For subproblem $(1.2)$, I guess that the optimal scaling factor $\alpha=1/\sqrt{N}$ since the optimal $\mathbf{C}$ should be row-normalized, and I do not know how to get the optimal $\mathbf{B}$.

$(3.3)$ I guess that I can get a bipolar $\mathbf{B}$ by discretizing each element of $\mathbf{A}$ with

$$
b_{i,j}=f\left( a_{i,j} \right) =\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 -1,\ a_{i,j}<0\\
 1,\ a_{i,j}\ge 0\\
\end{array} \right.,
$$

$~~~~~~~~~$which may be better than random ones (by Bernoulli sampling) but not optimal?

---

**$4.$ Some Other Minor Questions:**

$(4.1)$ I do not know if I can directly write that “$\mathbf{B}\in\{-1,+1\}^{M\times N}$”?

Comment: Regarding your approach to (3.1), this approach only works (as far as I know) if $\mathbf A$ is constrained to satisfy $\mathbf A \mathbf A^\top = I$, which is not the case here

Comment: Hi @BenGrossmann! For $(3.1)$, I guess that the orthogonal form $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\top=\mathbf{I}_M$ may be naturally satisfied since the optimal $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}^\top$ should keep the norms of data points (or optimal $\mathbf{A}$ should be row-normalized), and for keeping most information, intuitively, the optimal $\mathbf{A}$ should be row-orthogonal.

Comment: For $(1.2)$, I guess that the optimal $\mathbf{C}$ should be also row-orthogonal. For instance, $\mathbf{C}=\frac{1}{4}\left[ \begin{matrix} 1&  1&  1&  1\\ 1&  1&  -1&  -1\\ \end{matrix} \right] $ may be an optimal bipolar projection matrix for a specific data matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, I am confused by that if I can add some conditions or constraints [e.g. your mentioned one(s) for $(3.1)$], such that the subproblem $(1.2)$ can be easier to be solved like $(1.1)$? Or what can I do to reduce the difficulty of $(1.2)$?

Comment: The original subproblem $(1.2)$ is so hard for me. A method I can think of is writing a program to search the optimal bipolar matrix, with an $\mathcal{O}(2^{MN})$ time complexity. But this is quite inefficient and I still believe that there exists an analytic way to get it.

Comment: You may wanna look at this paper: [A Least-Squares Framework for Component Analysis][1]. If I remember correctly the model should be general enough to cover your cases (at least the first one!). 


[1]: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6186732

Comment: @RozaTh Thanks for the link. That IEEE paper is very nice. There is a copy of it on [CiteSeer](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.214.2448&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: $\def\a{\alpha}\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{trace}\LR{#1}}
\def\rank#1{\operatorname{rank}\LR{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Here's a partial result for subproblem $(1.2).\;$
Start by writing the problem in least-squares form (as in my answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4442612)), then calculate the trace
$$\eqalign{
C^TC &= XX^+ \\
\trace{C^TC} &= \trace{XX^+} \\
\a^2\trace{B^TB} &= \rank{X} \\
\a^2MN &= D \\ \a^2 &= \fracLR{D}{MN} \\
}$$

Comment: Hi @greg, I am not sure if $(1.2)$ can be solved by the following two steps: First, for a given regularization parameter $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^+$, calculate an optimal (could be not bipolar ) $\mathbf{B}_\lambda=\underset{\mathbf{B}}{\text{arg}\min}\frac{1}{2}\lVert \alpha ^2\mathbf{B}^{\top}\mathbf{BX}-\mathbf{X} \rVert _{F}^{2}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\sum_{i,j}{\left( 1-b_{ij}^{2} \right) ^2}
$. So I posted the previous question and try to get the explicit form of $\mathbf{B}_\lambda$. Second, calculate the limit $\mathbf{B}=\underset{\lambda \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim}\ \mathbf{B}_{\lambda}$.

Comment: The subproblem $(1.1)$ may become the special case with $\lambda=0$ and $\mathbf{B}_0=\mathbf{A}/\alpha$. But how can I get the $\mathbf{B}_\lambda$ with a penalty term (which is not limited to be the above one)? I was aiming to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\lVert \mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{AX}-\mathbf{X} \rVert _{F}^{2}$, combine the results and let the derivative be zero to get the optimal intermediate matrix.

Comment: The gradient is
$$\tfrac{\partial}{\partial A}\big\|A^TAX-X\big\|_F^2
 \;=\; 2AA^TAXX^T + 2AXX^TA^TA - 4AXX^T$$
Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, after a long struggle, I can still not solve the weighted optimization problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\b{\beta}\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\size#1{\operatorname{size}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradd#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$You can use the logistic function to find an approximate solution to subproblem $(1.3)$
$$\eqalign{
\s(z) &= \fracLR{\o}{\o+e^{-z}} &\qiq \gradd{\s}{z} = \s-\s^2  \\
}$$
Introduce an unconstrained matrix $U$ as the new independent variable and define $C$ as the element-wise logistic function
$$\eqalign{
C &= \s(U) = {J}\oslash\LR{J+e^{-U}} \qiq\c{dC = (C-C\odot C)\odot dU} \\
}$$
where $J$ is the all-ones matrix and $(\odot,\oslash)$ denote  elementwise multiplication and division.

Use the gradient wrt $C$ to compute the gradient wrt $U$
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|C^TCX-X\|_F^2 \\
\grad{\phi}{C} &= 2CC^TCXX^T + 2CXX^TC^TC - 4CXX^T \;\doteq\; H\\
d\phi &= H:\c{dC} \\
  &= H:\CLR{(C-C\odot C)\odot dU} \\
  &= \LR{(C-C\odot C)\odot H}:dU \\
\grad{\phi}{U} &= (C-C\odot C)\odot H \;\doteq\; G \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}
 \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
A:(B\odot C) &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij}
 \;=\; (A\odot B):C \\
\\
}$$

---

Now that you have an analytical expression for the gradient, you can use
any gradient descent method to solve the zero gradient condition.

A typical step in such an algorithm will look like
$$\eqalign{
U_{k+1} &= U_k - \l_k G_k \\
}$$
where $k$ is the iteration counter and $\l_k$ is the step-length parameter which will depend on the particular gradient method that is used. Personally, I find the [Barzilai-Borwein method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1574405/357854) using Raydan's non-monotone line search to be effective and easy to code.

Using the *vanilla* logistic function, the components of $A$ are approximately equal to zero or one, but this approximation can be improved by introducing a sharpening parameter $\b\gg\o$
$$\eqalign{
\s_\b(z)
 &= \fracLR{\o}{\o+e^{-\b z}}
 &\qiq \gradd{\s_\b}{z} = \b\LR{\s-\s^2}  \\
}$$
As the parameter increases, the components of $A$ converge to either zero or one.

Comment: I think that this answer provides me a flexible approach since I can through modulating $\beta$ to control the approximation strength, and use $\sigma_\beta(\cdot)$ and $[2\sigma_\beta(\cdot)-1]$ to obtain the approximated binary and bipolar results, respectively.

Comment: I will use this method to jointly optimize all parameters, including the matrix and scaling factor $\alpha$.

Comment: I am particularly grateful to @greg for his/her timely help and constructive suggestions.